# Interpretation of sampling distribution as the main distinction between Bayesian and classical statistics (Leamer)

Tags: bayesian, sampling, interpretation, frequentist, philosophical

In [Hendry et al. (1990)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3532275.pdf) p. 187-188, Edward Leamer says:

> **To me the essential difference between the Bayesian and a classical point of view is** not that the parameters are treated as random variables, but rather **that the sampling distributions are treated as subjective distributions or characterizations of states of mind**. Thus, I can compound those with a subjective prior distribution. Nobody is going to object that there exists a subjective prior distribution, but people will object that this prior distribution can be multiplied by a sampling distribution, which some people think of as characterizing a "natural process." To me they both reflect states of mind. And by "states of mind" what I mean is the opinion that it is useful for me to operate as if the data were generated in a certain way.

(Emphasis is mine.)

To me the distinction Leamer makes is counterintuitive. I think (based on the context within the article) it addresses the question of whether we should believe in the existence of a true, immutable data generating process. I had not heard this mentioned discussing essential differences between Bayesians and classical statisticians before. But this was said 30 years ago.

**Questions:** Is Leamer's point salient among the Bayesians? Has it ever been salient?

**References:**

- Hendry, D. F., Leamer, E. E., & Poirier, D. J. (1990). [The ET Dialogue: A Conversation on Econometric Methodology](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3532275.pdf). *Econometric Theory, 6*(2), 171-261.

Comment: It is interesting that no Bayesians have offered an answer to your question yet.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt, yeah. About [a quarter of my questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a53690%20is%3aquestion%20answers%3a0) have not been answered, though I find most of them quite interesting.